# update statement with two or more inner join oracle and calculate values also select from a view

Tags: sql, oracle, join, sql-update, inner-join

I get a error that FROM Keyword not found where expected. Please let me know what might be wrong in the below code. I am trying to do update using two inner joins and also doing a select from an other view. Please let me know how this can be accomplished in oracle.

```
  update (Select asset.CRV_AMOUNT as ACRV, 
                 cmd.CRV_PERCENT  as CRVP, 
                 (select CRV$ 
                    from recapt.facility_rec_crv_V fac_v 
                   where fac_v.fac_code = fac.code 
                     AND fac_v.complex_code = fac.complex_code) CRV_TOTAL as CRVT 
            from recapt.asset asset
                 inner join  recapt.facility_rec fac
                    on fac.code = asset.fac_rec_code and 
                       fac.complex_code = asset.complex_code
                 inner join recapt.cost_model_detail cmd
                    on cmd.cost_model_id = fac.cost_model_id and
                       cmd.mf_division_id = asset.mf_division_id) t
     SET t.ACRV = ((t.CRVP * t.CRVT)/100);
```

Comment: you double-aliased(`) CRV_TOTAL as CRVT `)  scalar sub-query. Plus this is not an updatable view.

Comment: so can i just use CRV_TOTAL ?

Comment: I changed that now i get " cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table"

Comment: [There you go](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/views001.htm#i1006318). Also [this one](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/views001.htm#ADMIN11782)

Comment: is there no other way to read from the view to calculate as i am not editing the view value in my query

Comment: You are not only reading data, you are trying to `update` that view. `as i am not editing the view value in my query` then what `update .. set ..` statement you need for?

Answer (score 1):

You can try switching to MERGE statement - it will probably be much easier to code and understand.
I cannot test this, but something in the lines of:

```
merge into recapt.asset asset
using (select fac.code,
              fac.complex_code,
              cmd.mf_division_id,
              cmd.crv_percent as crvp,
              (select crv$
                 from recapt.facility_rec_crv_v fac_v
                where fac_v.fac_code = fac.code
                  and fac_v.complex_code = fac.complex_code) as crvt
         from recapt.facility_rec fac
        inner join recapt.cost_model_detail cmd
           on cmd.cost_model_id = fac.cost_model_id) t
    on (asset.fac_rec_code = t.code and
        asset.complex_code = t.complex_code and
        asset.mf_division_id = t.mf_division_it)
  when matched then
    update set asset.acrv = (t.crvp * t.crvt) / 100;
```

If you provide create table and insert statements (with some small amount of test data) I may be able to test this and/or offer a better solution.